# AngularJS $rootScope in factory - reload data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

I have a factory calling a $resource. Upon refreshing the application entirely, this works as planned. But it not call the resource again throughout navigating the application. Ideally i would like the $resource called every time i call the factory from the controller.

```
app.factory("factoryList", function ($cookieStore, $resource, $http, $location, $window) {

   var List = $resource('/api/list');
   $http.defaults.headers.common['auth-token'] = $cookieStore.get("api_key") + ':' + $cookieStore.get("api_token");
   return List.get();

});
```

This is my controller:

```
consoleApp.controller('mainController', function ($rootScope, $window, $scope, $resource, $http, $route, $location, $cookieStore, factoryList) {

$rootScope.list = factoryList;

});
```

Comment: Could you describe what this controller is going to accomplish and the context in which it is used?  (Is it mapped in a route/ngController directive/some other method)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle I created
    jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/5833/,
    I can see the content updated between navigations